# Video Conference on web

Tags: asp.net, flash

i have to create a voice conference for our website

what do you thing will be the best option

.Net or Flash ?

Comment: this is a question i am not sure whether flash or asp.net will give a better support

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check 'Adobe Flash Media Server' this is a really cool video and audio streaming server. You may check Flash Media Server Developer Center it :[here](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flashmediaserver/)

Answer (score 1):

ASP.NET is server side technology so I'm not sure how do you want to use it for voice conferencing, maybe you meant Silverlight?

Flash is IMO a winner because 99% of your users already have Flash installed. Silverlight is, on other hand, only 25%.

Comment: i have heard that flash has a good support for webcam and voice than  Asp.net